# Help finding a combinatorial proof of $k {n \choose k } = n {n - 1 \choose k -1}\;$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, examples-counterexamples, combinatorial-proofs

> I am unsatisfied with the answers 
>   [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528927/help-finding-a-combinatorial-proof-of-k-n-choose-k-n-n-1-choose-k-1). (Half of which used algebraic methods despite being advised not to!)

Help finding a combinatorial proof of $k {n \choose k } = n {n - 1 \choose k -1}$

I have completed the algebraic proof, it was easy. I am unsure how to do a combinatorial proof, or what exactly that pertains to.

Is this the expression needed:

$$\begin{pmatrix} n+1\\r\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}n\\r\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}n\\r-1\end{pmatrix}$$$$???$$

Comment: try writing the expressionbs out explicitly, using factorials. you'll see some simplifications

Comment: Hint: Suppose you want $k$ students from a high school class of $n$ students to be student representatives, with one of them having the title of class president. How would you count the number of possibilities?

Comment: @Semiclassical Isn't that just logic though? That wouldn't count as a combinatorial proof would it?

Comment: A combinatorial proof is showing that you can count the same set of objects in two different ways, and that the's equivalent to the combinatorial identity of interest being true.

Comment: @Semiclassical Really, that seems bizarre. So is there no way(non-algebraically) of proving the above Mathematically(easily)?

Comment: There may be other methods, but I don't see what's bizarre about this one (which certainly doesn't use algebra in any depth). Double-counting approaches are quite common in combinatorics and are perfectly rigorous if spelled out correctly.

Comment: The first answer in the topic you mention gives a combinatorial proof. Could you make clear why you are not satisfied with this?

Comment: That proof is *combinatorial*, with no "algebra" taint. One can more or less mechanically turn it into a *bijective* proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will prove the general statement.

$$ \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m} = \binom{n}{m} \binom{n-m}{k-m}$$

Let $S$ be an $n$ set. Consider the set $T$ of all ordered pairs $(A,B)$ where $A$ is $k$-subset of $S$ and $B$ is an $m$-subset of A. We prove this statement by counting the elements in $T$ in two ways.

- Set $A \subseteq S$ can be choosen in $\binom{n}{k}$ and set $B
     \subseteq A$ can be chosen in $\binom{k}{m}$ ways and so $|T| = 
     \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{m} $
- An $m$-subset $B$ of $S$ cab be choosen in $\binom{n}{m}$ ways for
  each choice of set $B$, choose a $(k-m)$-subset $C$ of $S-B$ and let
  $A = B \cup C$. Then $A$ is a $k$ subset of S and $B \subseteq C$.
  Thus the number of ways of choosing set $A$ is equal to number of
  ways of choosing set $C= \binom{n-m}{k-m}$. Hence $|T|= \binom{n}{m}
     \binom{n-m}{k-m} $.

And so result follows. 
For this problem take $m=1$ $\Box$